# How to uninstall Xcode 5.0.2 in 10.8.5 Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode5, osx-mountain-lion

I want to uninstall Xcode 5.0.2 in 10.8.5 Mountain Lion, But I am not able to do.

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all or sudo /Library/Developer/uninstall-devtools –mode=all does not work

it gives the result sudo: /Library/Developer/uninstall-devtools: command not found

Comment: Isn't Xcode installed under /Applications and not /Developer?

Answer (score -1):

You have to delete the Xcode.app as well. I had Xcode installed from App Store and did the following to uninstall it.

```
sudo /Library/Developer/4.1/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
sudo rm -r /Applications/Xcode.app
```

After that i could re-install it from App Store.